# Make values zero for specific days in a week and add them evenly across other days for same week

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-statements

I have this sample dataset. I am trying to figure out a formula in Excel to make the values for Saturday and Sunday zero for each week then take the sum of these two days and add it evenly across the remaining five days of the same week.

For e.g. in the table in image attached below for week 19, Sun = 1 and Sat = 7. In the output, I want the values for Sun and Sat to be changed to zero but the sum Sun = 1 and Sat=7 which is 8 needs to be divided equally among the remaining five days 8/5 =  1.6 and then added to the remaining days for the same week. I need to do this for every week.

Output Sample

[image]

I have tried using a formula like this but not sure what to do next:
=IF(OR(B3="Sat",B3="Sun"),0,D3+((VLOOKUP(CONCAT(C3,B3),$E$2:$G$15,2,FALSE))/2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First test if Sun or Sat.  Then use SUMIFS to return the value for those two days and divide by 5 and add it to the value:

```
 =IF(OR(A2={"Sun","Sat"}),0,SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,B2,A:A,{"Sun","Sat"}))/5+C2)
```

[image]

---

Or if one has Office 365 and wants a spillable formula:

```
=LET(
    dy,A2:A15,
    wk,B2:B15,
    sl,C2:C15,
    wkend,(dy="Sun")+(dy="Sat"),
    IF(wkend,0,SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,wk,A:A,{"Sun";"Sat"}))/5+sl)
    )
```

[image]